# Which System tables does the spark cassandra connector use?

Tags: java, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using username and password to connect to cassandra, not the super user.
Using the same user with spark give authorization exception.
spark tries to connect to `system.size_estimates`.
Which are the other system tables does spark cassandra connector use.
I need the information to to get the access from DBA.
Also I would like to know whether READ permission is enough or WRITE is also required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cassandra tables that the spark-cassandra-connector 1.6 is using are

- **system.size_estimates**
- **system.peers**
- **system.local**

read access should be enough.

Comment: Can you please give the source of the info

Comment: I checked the source code. Those are the only table queried.

Comment: I meant, those are the only system table queried. I didn't search for other table (system_auth etc...) as you are only interested in the tables from the system keyspace, right?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was looking for some document where this can be found. I will look the code for system_auth keyspace.

Comment: is there a way we can skip system table connections?
I have a user who has sufficient permission to explore a db, but doesnt have permission to system table.